# Efficiently doing prime factorisation by hand

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, totient-function

I have a yes/no question first (if 2 questions are allowed in 1 post).

When doing prime factorisation for using the Euler totient function can you use a particular prime more than once. (i.e. $p_{1} = 5, p_{2} = 3, p_{3} = 5$)?

What is the best way to do prime factorisation by hand? I have managed to factorise 1125 into $5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 3 \cdot 3$

However this is a small number and I managed to factorise it through intuition and no specific method.

What is an efficient way to do this by hand, and are the above prime factors correct?

Thanks for any answers in advance.

Comment: If you're unsure about the factorization of a small number, you can just multiply the factors. With larger numbers, there is the problem that you might fail to recognize that an odd number is the product of two or more large primes. For example, don't try to factor 57625516252672389617626 by hand, you won't get very far after dividing out the 2.

Comment: This is a rather cosmetic detail: you should put your factorization into some sort of canonical format, e.g., $3^2 \times 5^3$. Of course when dealing with many more repeated prime factors, as in, for example, 20503125, the exponents are a big help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Regarding the totient, $\phi(mn)=\phi(m)\phi(n)$ only if $m,n$ are relatively prime.  Hence not only may you use a prime more than once, you *must* pull out all copies of a prime, then treat them all together:  $\phi(p^k)=p^k-p^{k-1}$.
2. Your factorization of $1125$ is correct, as is your strategy (divide by small primes as much as possible).

Comment: So because $x$ is not relatively prime to $x$, I cannot use a prime more than once when trying to compute the euler totient?

Comment: That's right, $\phi(25)\neq \phi(5)\phi(5)$.

Comment: So I must factorise 1125 into different prime numbers. None can be identical?

Comment: $\phi(1125)=\phi(5^33^2)=\phi(5^3)\phi(3^2)=(5^3-5^2)(3^2-3^1)$.

Comment: Had to think about that one but I got it. Cheers, thanks a lot for the answer !